# SQL -- Finding students taking 2 or more classes

Tags: mysql, sql

I had this question in an interview, and I couldn't quite figure it out.  I have three tables: a student table, a classes table and a table linking the other two.  Here is a basic schema for them.

```
STUDENT
student_id | student_name
-----------+-------------
int        | varchar(30)

CLASS
class_id | class_name
---------+-----------
int      | varchar(30)

ROSTERS
student_id | class_id
-----------+---------
int        | int
```

The rosters table shows which students are taking which classes.  How do I write a query showing which students are taking 2 or more classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will do what you want:

```
SELECT s.student_name, COUNT(DISTINCT r.class_id) AS num_classes
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN rosters r ON r.student_id = s.student_id
GROUP BY s.student_id
HAVING num_classes >= 2
```

It counts all the distinct `class_id` values in `roster` for each student (`num_classes`) and returns only students with 2 or more (`HAVING num_classes >= 2`).

Note I've used a `LEFT JOIN` to catch all students, however since you want only those with more than 1 class this is not necessary and you could use a straight `JOIN`.

Also note that it's not necessary to `JOIN` the `class` table for this question, however if you wanted the names of the classes the student was taking you would need to.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select  s.*,r.*,c.*,count(*) 
from 
student s,
class c,
rosters r where
s.student_id=r.student_id and
c.class_id=r.class_id
group by s.student_id 
having count(*)>=2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`, `count`, `having` and `group by` to get the required output:

```
select r.student_id,s.student_name,count(*) 
from STUDENT s inner join ROSTERS r
on s.student_id = r.student_id
group by r.student_id,s.student_name
having count(*)>=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two tables, STUDENT and ROSTERS (I have used inner join, if required, this can be changed as per requirements), counting the number of classes each student is taking.

```
SELECT s.student_name, 
    COUNT(r.class_id) AS count
FROM 
    STUDENT s
INNER JOIN 
    ROSTERS r 
ON 
    r.student_id = s.student_id
GROUP BY 
    s.student_id
HAVING 
    count >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(class_id), student_id 
FROM Rosters 
GROUP BY student_id 
HAVING COUNT(class_id) >=2
```

This is the simplest way to do it IMO.